# Get path of the resource folder inside spring boot jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties, resources, gcloud

i am trying convert java application project to spring boot, and i am trying to deploy this spring boot project jar in gcp by using below cmd

```
gcloud app deploy <projectname>.jar
```

inside my application i am using one of the apache core dependency which needs 2 property files and it is  placed under project directory

```
--PROJECTNAME<root>
----/.idea
----/config/bin/config.properties
----/src
------/main
------/...
------/...
```

and i can set only the path for the property files remaining things will be handled by the apache dependency class files. it is working fine in IDE and as a jar if those properties are available in jar location itself.

so when i deploy this project in gcp using above cmd i can see this project is copied under /workspace/ directory in gcp app engine. so either i need to copy this property files under /workspace/ directory in gcp or i need to access the property file inside the jar but i can only pass the path(String).
in apache class file below code is used to read the property files.

```
BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader((new File( <path which i can pass> + "/bin/config.properties")).toPath(), Charset.defaultCharset());
and 
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(<path which i can pass> + "/bin/config.properties");
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can put your config files inside src/main/resources, as I can see your config is outside from src dir, so then in the class you need the file you can do `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("config/bin/config.properties")` to get the file as a URL and open a InputStream for it.